# How to write simple jasmine and karma test for angular project for addition of object to an object array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have created a normal employee project in angular and need to test the `addproduct` function. How should I write a test case for this. I don't use service it is a simple push functionality. Any help on this will be helpful

```
public products = [{
     name:"Moto G5",
     quantity:2
  },
  {
     name:"Racold Geyser",
     quantity:3 
  }];

  addproduct(name: string,quantity:number) {

      var details = {name:name,quantity:quantity};
      this.products.push(details);

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test such functions,  you should try below block:

```
it('should be created', () => {
  component.products.length = 2;
  component.addproduct("test",1);  
  expect(component.products.length).toBe(3);
  expect(component.products[2].name).toBe("test");
});
```

Since you are new to Angular testing, I would strongly recommend you to read [this article which has some more links in the last paragraph.](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7?source=---------11------------------)

It would surely help you to understand testing in a very easy yet standard way.

Happy Testing !

Comment: Hi Shashank, Thank you for answering I went through your blogs. Can you exactly mention the similar use case you have covered in your blog.

Comment: @JananiSridhar : Not the exact same cases but you'll get some idea if you'll go through https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49 and  https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-basic-html-elements-using-karma-jasmine-in-angular-fd5e4ac62d78 . Its impossible to cover all scenarios as it varies from code to code. The main essence is to know what unit test is all about

Answer (score 1):

@shashank Vivek thanks for your answer. The below code worked for me in testing the add product method to test whether we are able to add the product to the already existing array of objects.

```
it('should be created', () => {
  component.products.length = 2;
  component.addproduct("test",1);  
  expect(component.products.length).toBe(3);
  expect(component.products[2].name).toBe("test");
});
```

Comment: Good effort . I hope my article would help u